# PHP compare two Array Keys and combine into a new Array(Wrong format)

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays and want to compare the same keys of **array_1 and array_2** and combine them into a new Array like **array_3**

**Coding**

```
$array_1['value1']="";
$array_1['value2']="";
$array_1['value3']="";
$array_1['value4']="";
$array_1['value5']="";

$array_2['value1']="5";
$array_2['value3']="10";
$array_2['value5']="15";

/*
I want the format to be like this after merging.

$array_3['value1']="5";
$array_3['value2']="";
$array_3['value3']="10";
$array_3['value4']="";
$array_3['value5']="15";

*/

$results=array_merge_recursive($array_1,$array_2);
echo '<pre>',print_r($results),'</pre>';
```

[image]
By using **array_merge_recursive**, the array format is not what I want. Anyone has idea how to get the result format like the right side of the screenshot?

Comment: Just using `array_merge()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinary `array_merge` should do the trick:

```
<?php

$array_1['value1']="";
$array_1['value2']="";
$array_1['value3']="";
$array_1['value4']="";
$array_1['value5']="";

$array_2['value1']="5";
$array_2['value3']="10";
$array_2['value5']="15";

/*
I want the format to be like this after merging.

$array_3['value1']="5";
$array_3['value2']="";
$array_3['value3']="10";
$array_3['value4']="";
$array_3['value5']="15";

*/

$results=array_merge($array_1,$array_2);
echo print_r($results);
```

The result:

```
Array
(
    [value1] => 5
    [value2] => 
    [value3] => 10
    [value4] => 
    [value5] => 15
)
1
```